# Jenkins java.lang.Exception: State is invalid

Tags: jenkins

Seeing this error when going to Jenkins.

```
java.lang.Exception: State is invalid
```

The solution is probably something super simple that I'm just missing. I couldn't find any results when Googling that exception (unless I failed at that too).

Right now our Jenkins is being served on 2 URLs, one works fine and the other throws the exception defined above.

Comment: Can you post the error trace? Only one exception is not so relevant!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was we needed to change all of the configs to the new URL. Even though apache points to the right port, the application needs to know about the URL it's being ran on.